# delphi XE5: Tooltip evaluation expression not working any more

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-xe5

I have a really strange and annoying problem with my XE5 install. Since this morning, I cannot get the debugger to properly show me tooltip evaluation when I hover my mouse over a variable and the "local variable" debug window is always empty.

I *think* it started when I tried to setup remote debugging on another windows machine but I'm not sure (I didn't pay close attention to the debugging system at that time: I was just trying to get it work through the firewalls).

Since then, I verified that all debug options in general and Code Insight options in particular are [properly set](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Tooltips_During_Debugging), I restarted the IDE, the machine, deleted the connection profile, tried it with a blank new project, etc: nothing seems to be able to restore the debugger capability to show hints.

While debugging a win32 process, evaluation (Ctrl+F7), Watches (Ctrl+F5) and breakpoints (F5) all work but inspection (alt+F5) does not.

I also tried a win64 app, a Firemonkey win32 app, and a firemonkey maxOS X app debugged with the PAServer: I have exactly the same issue with each one.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Edit: This is limited to XE5. I'm also using Delphi 6 (I know...) and the code insight evaluation tooltips are working there just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem and fixed it.

Basically, a couple of "Known IDE packages" were missing from the registry, probably following a messy uninstall from the "DKLang" translation system:

```
$(BDS)\Bin\dbkdebugide190.bpl
$(BDS)\bin\dbkdebugproide190.bpl
```

I found that out comparing a dump of my registry and the dump from a co-worker's.